# Write request and receive a response with web chat bot

Tags: c#, web, webclient, chatbot

I'm trying to create simple interface to analyze conversation with different available web chatter bots. So I have no idea in which direction I've to research, if only thing I want is a write massage to the chatterbot for example **cleverbot.com** from the textbox of my application and get answer string from it. if I can figure it out with this, then I want get the list of available web chat bots to choose. Maybe I can use WebClient for this goal, need any advice on this direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at **SignalR** from Microsoft.

In their [tutorial](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) they provide an example for a chat.

[image: SignalR example]

i would not try to implement a chat functionality by yourself. Posting all chat messages over your server and poll them from the clients was state of the art in the 90's.

(Picture taken from [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr))

Comment: Hello I tried but got error with debugging _Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer._  not sure what I should install

Comment: hm. i would suggest to read the docs. SignalR is well documented and there are many examples out there. sorry i can not give you any further assistance. But you asked for a hint how to solve your question.